# How to import JS library to typescript in React Native project

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

How can I import js library (in my case xhook library) into my react native project written in typescript? Or How can I create typescript header file for external js library?

Comment: See if this helps? https://github.com/philikon/ReactNativify

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
const signalrLib = require("react-native-signalr").default
```

Answer (score 5):

TypeScript compiles to plain Javascript just like Babel or any other extended Javascript language.

So when you add example `xhook` to your project, project owner has already compiled his/her TypeScript code into plain JS and you import it just like any other library.

eg. `import xhook from 'xhook'` or so on how library author has specified.

You can see it yourself if you visit xhook's git page https://github.com/jpillora/xhook you can see compiled code in folder `dist` and in `package.json` -file, attribute `main` points to that file.

TypeScript is not itself language that is runned in browser, but that it is always compiled to plain JavaScript. Hopefully this helps out making a grasp how this works.

edit. seems like `xhook`is actually written in CoffeeScript but this same rule applies to it as well.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, You can use any ES6/ES2015 notation in typescript.
With the new typescript, import will be

```
import xhook from 'xhook';
```

Older version:

```
import * as xhook from 'xhook'
```

Some module doesnt have type support. You can look for type support as

```
yarn add @types/xhook
```

If you dont find type support you can use, node require syntax

```
const xhook = require('xhook');
```

For that you may have to declare, **require** definition like:

```
declare const require: any;
```